# Predual of Morrey space

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

The domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$

I have a question about the $H^{p,\lambda}$, the dual of Morrey space $L^{p',\lambda}$. Let $C_0$ is the space of continuous functions have the compact support. The Morrey space is the set of functions $f$ such that: 
$$\sup_{r>0,x_o\in\mathbb{R}^n }[r^{\lambda-n}\int_{B(x_0,r)}|f(y)|^{p'}dy]^{1/p'}$$

The dual of this space is:[image]

[image]

[image]
The book: Morrey space - David R.Adam.

My question is whu $C_0$ is dense in $H^{p,\lambda}$?

Thank you for your help.